# date range related error on Pentaho ETL

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm doing a data migration from oracle 9i datasource to Sql Server 2008 one, but this is failing because of this error : '`Only dates between January 1, 1753 and December 31, 9999 are accepted.'`
The problem is that on Sql Server 2008 database, I'm using datetime2 datatype, which allows wider range of dates. here is the complete trace that Spoon is displaying :

```
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - copy_maffiche_commune_to_s - ERROR (version 6.0.1.0-386, build 1 from 2015-12-03 11.37.25 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - ERROR (version 6.0.1.0-386, build 1 from 2015-12-03 11.37.25 by buildguy) : Because of an error, this step can't continue:
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - ERROR (version 6.0.1.0-386, build 1 from 2015-12-03 11.37.25 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Error inserting row into table [AFFICHE_COMMUNE] with values: [25063], [24], [224], [49], [3], [0206/02/26 00:00:00.000], [0], [0], [null]
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - offending row : [NUM_DOSSIER Integer(6)], [INDICE String(3)], [CODE_SERVICE_FONCIER Integer(3)], [CODE_AFFICHAGE Integer(3)], [CODE_COMMUNE Integer(4)], [DATE_ETAPE Date], [REFERENCE Integer(4)], [NUMERO_DEPOT Integer(6)], [VOLUME_DEPOT String(10)]
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Error setting value #6 [Date] on prepared statement
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Only dates between January 1, 1753 and December 31, 9999 are accepted.
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:377)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:118)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - offending row : [NUM_DOSSIER Integer(6)], [INDICE String(3)], [CODE_SERVICE_FONCIER Integer(3)], [CODE_AFFICHAGE Integer(3)], [CODE_COMMUNE Integer(4)], [DATE_ETAPE Date], [REFERENCE Integer(4)], [NUMERO_DEPOT Integer(6)], [VOLUME_DEPOT String(10)]
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Error setting value #6 [Date] on prepared statement
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Only dates between January 1, 1753 and December 31, 9999 are accepted.
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.setValues(Database.java:1023)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:254)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    ... 3 more
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Error setting value #6 [Date] on prepared statement
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Only dates between January 1, 1753 and December 31, 9999 are accepted.
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - 
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.setPreparedStatementValue(ValueMetaBase.java:4867)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.setValue(Database.java:1005)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.setValues(Database.java:1021)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    ... 4 more
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Only dates between January 1, 1753 and December 31, 9999 are accepted.
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.DateTime.packDate(DateTime.java:318)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:126)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setParameter(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:444)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:840)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:870)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.setPreparedStatementValue(ValueMetaBase.java:4811)
2016/04/13 15:45:21 - write to [AFFICHE_COMMUNE].0 -    ... 6 more
```

What could be the origin of this problem ?

Comment: Looks like the prepared statement Pentaho creates for Date datatypes it doesn't use your destination data types, but a pre-canned data type, probably datetime, hence the error.

Comment: thanks for the debugging hint  @KyleHale :) Is it possible to modify how Pentaho uses datatypes ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use a Timestamp data type for fields that are being mapped into datetime2 fields in SQL Server, as Date is implicitly converted to a datetime field.

To modify data types, after your table input, under "Select Values" there is a metadata tab, you can set data types for your input fields there.

I'll try to get a screenshot later.

Comment: how can i achieve that ?

Comment: @mounaim Updated my answer for you.

Comment: any screenshot for this operation ? If I can modify in the .ktr files (the xml transformation files) that would also be great :)